# OAuth GitHub Redirect Url. Prevent code parameter from appearing in the url of my webpage

Tags: angularjs, oauth, github-api

I have successfully gotten Oauth to work with GitHub, my angular client and my java server. However, I am uneasy about the callback url with the code query string parameter in my url bar.

I traced slacks integration with GitHub through the console and was able to locate the code query string parameter, but never saw it in the url address bar. I was curious how they accomplished this and would like to do the same sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because of a redirection (listed in [GitHub API V3 HTTP Redirects](https://developer.github.com/v3/#http-redirects))

> 302: Temporary redirection.
>   The request should be repeated verbatim to the URI specified in the Location header field but clients should continue to use the original URI for future requests.

See an example at "[Hiding OAuth Callback URL Parameters](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/11351)".